# windows Script file which continuously look out on a user app and restarts automatically if it closes?

Tags: windows, terminal, scripting, windows-7

Hi guys how do i go about write an .bat file where it should do the following

```
1) on running the script file-> my user app must be executed.
2) continuously  or periodically checks  if user app is running 
3) if app closes it should start the app again.
```

and also, i have a doubt as when my user app crashes its doesn't closes completely
application stopped working error is displayed, how do i bypass this so that my bat file can detect that app is closed and needs to be opened. ??
i am completely new to this so any hints and help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a counter=60
:again
tasklist|FINDSTR /i /b /L "boinc.exe" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 cls&exit
timeout /t 6 >NUL
SET /a counter-=1
IF %counter% gtr 0 GOTO again 
SET /a counter=60
ECHO execute BOINC
START "boinc" "C:\Program Files\eFMer\BoincTasks\boinctasks64.exe"
GOTO again
```

I use this batch to ensure that `boinc.exe` starts (this is for running research science in the background).

If the `if not errorlevel 1...` line is changed to

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 timeout /t 60 >NUL&goto again
```

then the check will be re-run every 60 seconds. As it stands, it is designed to delay 6 minutes between checks by timing out 6 second 60 times. This could be modified by setting `count` and `timeout` parameters to different values.

(you'd probably next want to search for how to run a batch file silently. There are articles here on SO - just use the `search` at the top of the page)

Comment: got to the top of the page. On the black bar, right-hand side, there is a `search` facility. Try searching there for `batch silent`. It normally involves a .vbs routine as batch doesn't have a silent mode - although it's probably possible using `task sceduler`

Answer (score 1):

Refer following link for executing exe from .bat file:- http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001345.htm

But I am not sure if you can able to detect running app using .bat file.
For detection of app you can write automation script for this.
All the best.